# Fixed IP address, hosting via Docker in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

We want to host our software on AWS via Docker using ECS. However, our software must connect to an external service, and they limit our access based on IP address.

Is it possible to have fixed IP addresses for the EC2 instances in the ECS cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by putting the instances in a private subnet and running their traffic through [a NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).